# Item moves when resizing window

Tags: html, css

recently I attempted to code my first theme for a blog, but I'm having a problem with my avatar moving when I resize the window vertically.

I see that this is a common question, but I've tried many of the solutions given and they haven't worked out. I tried wrapping the elements in one `<div id="wrapper">` and adding `position: absolute;` but the avatar continues to move. I've also tried putting a parent function with `position: relative` and nesting (is that the term?) the relevant elements inside with `position: absolute` to no avail. Everything else remains fixed despite resizing except the avatar. Here's the css:

```
  .avatar {
    position: fixed;
    left: 40px;
    bottom: 400px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 90px;
    border: 3px solid white;
  }
  .descripbox {
      position: fixed;
      left: 45px;
      top: 222px;
  }
  .titlebox {
      position: fixed;
      left: 45px;
      top: 210px;
  }
  .home {
      position: fixed;
      left: 190px;
      top: 60px;
  }
  .ask {
      position: fixed;
      left: 210px;
      top: 85px;
  }
  .themes {
      position: fixed;
      left: 220px;
      top: 110px;
  }
```

Here is the html:

```
<img class="avatar" src="{PortraitURL-128}">
    <div class="descripbox">
        {block:Description}
        <h2>{Description}</h2>
        {/block:Description}
    </div>
    <div class="titlebox"
    <h1><a href="{BlogURL}">{Title}</a></h1>
    </div>
    <div class="home">
        <li><a href="/">home</a></li>
    </div>
    <div class="ask">
        <li><a href="/faq">ask</a></li>
    </div>
    <div class="themes">
        <li><a href="/tagged/themes">themes</a></li>
    </div>
```

I'm a beginner so I've probably made some very obvious mistakes. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think you fixed your position of avatar from `bottom: 400px;` , instead try making your avatar position from top.

Comment: IT WORKED, thank you! But may I ask, why did it?

Comment: `fixed` positioning is relative to the window. If you specify the position based on the top of the window it'll stick to the top of the window and resizing the browser from the bottom won't affect it, and vice versa. It'll only move when that co-ordinate of the browser window changes.

Comment: @pastel : In this case you fixed the height from bottom, that you should always be away 500px from bottom, Now you changed the dependency from bottom to top. 
SO it is top dependent now :) xD
Cheers

Comment: @JackHasaKeyboard @ b0y I think I understand now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In ur code one of the div tag is not closed. Plz check after closing the tag

Correct one:

```
<div class="titlebox">
    <h1><a href="{BlogURL}">{Title}</a></h1>
    </div>
```

Close the following tag

```
<div class="titlebox"
    <h1><a href="{BlogURL}">{Title}</a></h1>
    </div>
```

Comment: Good catch! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether it is correct or not?
Do you need like this?
Missing close brace in the div element 
`<div class="titlebox">`

```
 <style>
     .avatar {
        position: fixed;
        left: 40px;
        bottom: 400px;
        border-radius: 100%;
        padding: 10px;
        border-radius: 90px;
        border: 3px solid white;
      }
      .descripbox {
          position: fixed;
          left: 45px;
          top: 222px;
      }
      .titlebox {
          position: fixed;
          left: 45px;
          top: 210px;
      }
      .home {
          position: fixed;
          left: 190px;
          top: 60px;
      }
      .ask {
          position: fixed;
          left: 210px;
          top: 85px;
      }
      .themes {
          position: fixed;
          left: 220px;
          top: 110px;
      }
    </style>
    <img class="avatar" src="{PortraitURL-128}">
        <div class="descripbox">
            {block:Description}
            <h2>{Description}</h2>
            {/block:Description}
        </div>
        <div class="titlebox">
        <h1><a href="{BlogURL}">{Title}</a></h1>
        </div>
        <div class="home">
            <li><a href="/">home</a></li>
        </div>
        <div class="ask">
            <li><a href="/faq">ask</a></li>
        </div>
        <div class="themes">
            <li><a href="/tagged/themes">themes</a></li>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove <strike>bottom:400px;</strike>

```
.avatar {
    position: fixed;
    left: 40px;

    border-radius: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 90px;
    border: 3px solid white;
  }
```